# difficulty creating jax-rpc stub with wscompile

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, java-me

I'm trying to create the method stubs for the following webservice http://playground.bioid.com/Content/BWS/www.bioid.com.2011.12.bws.wsdl (cloud based WCF using SOAP protocols) using wscompile. When i run the command

```
wscompile -gen -cldc1.1 config.xml
```

i get the following errors

```
error: Found unknown simple type: byte[]
error: Found unknown simple type: byte[]
info: Types were processed that are not supported by CLDC 1.0.
error: Found unknown simple type: byte[]
error: Found unknown simple type: byte[]
error: Found unknown simple type: byte[]
```

Any ideas how to go about this? 
I took a look at the xsd of the webservice and here's a snippet

```
<xs:element name="Enroll">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="classId" nillable="true" type="q1:BiometricClassID"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="samples" nillable="true" type="q2:ArrayOfSample"/> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="flags" type="q3:EnrollmentFlags"/>
  </xs:sequence>  
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'm guessing the **type="q........."** attributes are what's causing the problems?